# How can I fix parser Error in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I'm facing a parser error in ASP.NET, how can I handle it and why this error is coming? How can I resolve it?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BrightPublication.PurchaseOrderForm'.

Source Error:
```

Comment: You could try to find what's attempting to load type `BrightPublication.PurchaseOrderForm` on that page as a starting point.  Other than that I think we're going to need more information.

Comment: i am adding a web page using master page BrightPublication is project name and PurchaseOrderForm is the new page that i created and facing that error